# Determining the value of local variables using gdb in a function in shared library built with -g (gdb says no line number information)

Tags: gdb

List items 1- 4 are the steps that I did. 
List item 5 describes the problem
List item 6 provides additional information

1. I have compiled a C source code say c1.c with -g flag.
2. I have also a
   dynamic shared library say liba1.so built with -g for all the source
   files that it has.
3. I built the executable say exe1 by linking c1.o (c1.c object code) with the liba1.so .
4. I do gdb exe1. and am able to step through the sources of c1.c. When c1 calls the shared library, I am also able to *put a breakpoint on a function in the shared library*.
5. **However, when I try to step through the function, it says that "Single stepping until exit from function foo1 ,which has no line number information" Also it should ordinarily show the value of the parameters passed into the function foo1 but does not do that. This happens for all functions in the shared library including some very big ones so the values cannot be optimized out**
6. *I did an objdump -t on the shared library AND the executable - it shows the symbol table (the fact that I can set a breakpoint on the function also supports this). Also, I can see the values of the variables used in the file c1.c So what should I do in order to ensure that I can see the values of the local variables inside the shared library. Here are the other arguments that are being used to compile the shared library "-O2 -std=gnu99  -Werror   -fno-stack-protector -Wstack-protector   --param ssp-buffer-size=1 -g -nostdinc". doing info f and trying to look at memory addresses on the frame also does not give any information.*

I am looking for some suggestion to at least troubleshoot it. Can I know using objdump (or any other utility) if a shared library has line number information.

Comment: Please learn how to properly format your question. It's un-readable in its current state.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Have reformatted it

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for some suggestion to at least troubleshoot it.

The most likely reason for `no line number information`, is that there is *in fact* no line number information, and the most likely reason for that is that you have two copies of `liba1.so` -- one that has debug info, and one that doesn't, and you are loading at runtime the latter.

First step: `(gdb) info shared` will tell you *exactly* which `liba1.so` is loaded.

If it is in fact the version that you've just built with `-g`, you should verify that it does have the debug info you are expecting. The exact commands for doing so are platform specific (and you didn't tell which platform you are on). On an ELF platform, `objdump -g liba1.so` or `readelf -w liba1.so` should work.

One common reason for `-g` code to not have debug info is presence of `-s` (strip) flag on the link line; make sure you don't have "stray" flags on your link line. Some platforms also require `-g` to be used at link time in addition to compile time.